# How can I install the YR weather gem?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, windows-xp

I am trying to install the yr.no weather api gem from [here](http://irbno.rubyforge.org/yr/doc/) but am having problems adding the repository.

I tried `gem sources -a http://irbno.rubyforge.org/` but this results in the following error:

```
Error fetching http://irbno.rubyforge.org/: 
bad response Not Found 404 (http://irbno.rubyforge.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am on Windows XP with Ruby 1.9.2 and have updated to the latest version of Rubygems (1.5.2)

`ruby -v` returns

```
`ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]`
```

whilst `gem sources -l` returns

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
http://gemcutter.org
```

Any thoughts? Is this a problem with the repository or my setup?

Answer (score 0):

The correct URI for the RubyForge RubyGems Repository was `http://Gems.RubyForge.Org/`, not `http://IrBNo.RubyForge.Org/`. However, the RubyForge RubyGems repository was shut down a long time ago and migrated to RubyGems.Org, so that URI is now simply a redirect to `http://RubyGems.Org/` (as is `http://GemCutter.Org/` BTW).

Since you already have that repository URI in your RubyGems sources, you don't need to do anything.

May I ask where you found the information that `http://IrBNo.RubyForge.Org/` was the correct URI for the RubyForge RubyGems Repository? You should inform those people that their information is wrong (`http://IrBNo.RubyForge.Org/` never was the URI of the RubyForge RubyGems Repository, it always was `http://Gems.RubyForge.Org/`) and outdated (the default RubyGems Repository moved to `http://GemCutter.Org/` and then to `http://RubyGems.Org/` a long time ago).

Not that any of this really matters, since as far as I can tell, there was never a Gem released for this project anyway.

Comment: He might be able to download yr_api.gem from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=4520&release_id=20455 and install locally, though.

Comment: Thanks - that downloadable gem was just what I was looking for.